# Is there a way to free used memory in Spyder?

Tags: python, memory, web-scraping, spyder, scheduler

I have scheduled a python web-scraper to run everyday at specified time. This puts load on spyder memory after a while results in system crash. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Spyder the IDE? It's the python process that is using memory. Spyder has nothing to do with this directly. You shouldn't be running this from your IDE anyway. Anyway, Python is a memory managed language, there is no way to manually free memory. Likely, you've written your code in a way that doesn't allow python's garbage collection strategy (reference counting) to work

Comment: Can you please clarify what role Spyder memory plays in you Python script?  I’d presume the script would be run from cron or task scheduler ... not Spyder.  What am I missing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with using Spyder IDE for a process that I was running.
Things like deleting variables and using gc.collect() didn't work to free memory within a loop for my script on Ubuntu 20.04.

The way I got around having memory crash problems in long loops inside of Spyder was to run the script in terminal instead of Spyder using `python my_script.py`.  This worked for me and my loops or long processes aren't crashing my memory anymore!  Goodluck!